# Iterate through JSON file to show data for correct links in HTML modal with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, json, modal-dialog

I am trying to fill in my HTML modal with data from a JSON file and using JavaScript to show the correct data.

So, what I am trying to do is, I have a JSON file with some data for each team and when I click on the team name within the HTML, I want a modal to popup which shows the data for the selected team.

The modal popsup, but the data does not show.

Below, I am attaching my JSON, HTML and JavaScript

JSON:

```
[
  {
    "team": "Liverpool",
    "teamInfo": "One"
  },
  {
    "team": "Everton",
    "teamInfo": "Two"
  }
]
```

HTML:

```
<a class="openModal" data-modal-target="#modal-liverpool">
  <span class="team-img">
    <img src="">
    <span class="team">Liverpool</span>
  </span>
</a>

<a class="openModal" data-modal-target="#modal-everton">
  <span class="team-img">
    <img src="">
    <span class="team">Everton</span>
  </span>
</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="modal-liverpool">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="title"></div>
    <button data-close-button class="close">&times;</button>
  </div>
  <div class="body"></div>
</div>
<div id="overlay"></div>

<div class="modal" id="modal-everton">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="title"></div>
    <button data-close-button class="close">&times;</button>
  </div>
  <div class="body"></div>
</div>
<div id="overlay"></div>
```

Many thanks in advance!
JavaScript:

```
fetch('teams.json')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    for(var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
      var element = document.querySelector(".title");
      element.textContent = data[x].team;
    }
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need querySelectorAll

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".title");
data.forEach((item, i) => elements[i].textContent = item.team);
```

```js
const data = [{
    "team": "Liverpool",
    "teamInfo": "One"
  },
  {
    "team": "Everton",
    "teamInfo": "Two"
  }
]

const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".title");
data.forEach((item, i) => elements[i].textContent = item.team);
```

```html
<a class="openModal" data-modal-target="#modal-liverpool">
  <span class="team-img">
    <img src="">
    <span class="team">Liverpool</span>
  </span>
</a>

<a class="openModal" data-modal-target="#modal-everton">
  <span class="team-img">
    <img src="">
    <span class="team">Everton</span>
  </span>
</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="modal-liverpool">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="title"></div>
    <button data-close-button class="close">&times;</button>
  </div>
  <div class="body"></div>
</div>
<div id="overlay"></div>

<div class="modal" id="modal-everton">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="title"></div>
    <button data-close-button class="close">&times;</button>
  </div>
  <div class="body"></div>
</div>
<div id="overlay"></div>
```

Comment: Tnx for this, it has really helped